# how to use slice to get 1 by 1 loop python

Tags: python, slice

so i have code using visual basic:

```
for loop1 = 1 to panjangkata
    sedangolah$ = mid$(kataenkripsi$, loop1, 1)
    for loop2 = 1 to enkrip
        hasilenkrip$ = hasilenkrip$ + sedangolah$
    next loop2
next loop1
```

how to make to python? i want to crop 1 by 1 and loop it again

> example = 0011 -> it can be 00000000 11111111

i just know it must use slice, but what slice?

```
a[start:stop:step] // like this?
```

Comment: Please show us the Python code you tried. In Python string indexes are 0..N-1 where N is length of string.

Comment: Please clarify your question by providing sample input and required output

Comment: already in example @Vlad

Comment: im new in python, i just read and it say must to use slice. can you help? @vaizki

Comment: @HelpMe There is **nothing** in your question to explain the rationale behind translating 0011 to 00000000 11111111. Nor is there any explanation as to why you **must** use slicing. Why use a technique for the sake of it if it's inappropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to loop through the characters of the string in variable `kataenkripsi` and produce an output which repeats each character `enkrip` times:

```
kataenkripsi = '0011'
enkrip = 4
hasilenkrip = ''
for a in kataenkripsi:
    hasilenkrip += a * enkrip

print(hasilenkrip)
```

Produces

```
0000000011111111
```

Instead of looping integer indexes and slicing the input string, Python can just use the input as an iterable to produce the individual characters.

If you really want to index,

```
for loop1 in range(panjangkata):
    sedangolah = kataenkripsi[loop1:loop1+1]
    for loop2 in range(enkrip):
        hasilenkrip = hasilenkrip + sedangolah
```